# Present Participle(adjective) vs Progressive tense

Tags: present-participles, present-progressive, deverbal-adjectives

Mangoes are refreshing.
An adjective form is needed here.
But "auxiliary verb" + " verb-ing" act as progressive tense.
It may imply that mangoes are refreshing(something, if transitive OR even if intransitive, they are just refreshing).
So is "refreshing" acting as an adjective here. If yes then is it not violating the general concept of "auxiliary verb" + " verb-ing", acting as progressive tense?
Definitely, "refreshing" is not a gerund here.

Comment: Do the simple test. Mangoes are refreshing. So are oranges. Now let's compare their refreshingnesses. If *refreshing* is an adjective, we'll have to say "mangoes are more refreshing than oranges". If it's a verb, we'll have to say "mangoes are refreshing more than oranges" instead. And frankly, I do not know a single person who'd opt for the latter.

Comment: Good test. Another test is direct object; _Mangoes are refreshing me_ hasta be progressive (not the "progressive tense", btw, but the progressive construction) because adjectives can't take objects. Another is _very_; only adjectives can take _very_: _Mangoes are very refreshing_ but not **Mangoes are very refreshing me*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt ok but you have not answered the second part of my question : if it is acting as an adjective,  then is it not violating the general idea of helping verb + verb ing = progressive tense?

Comment: Flying aeroplanes can be dangerous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Participles of many verbs have an 'independent' status as *deverbal* adjectives—adjectives which have lost any sense of being verbs. This is frequent with verbs which signify effecting a state in a person:

> This is an interesting question.
> I'm no longer interested.
>
> This is a boring story.
> I'm bored.
>
> What an annoying child!
> Mary seems to be annoyed this morning.

The participles of *refresh* behave exactly the same way:

> These mangoes are refreshing.
> I feel quite refreshed this morning.

Comment: each of your examples are not related to the question. what about : This is interesting.  This is boring.  This is annoying. I have no doubt in : Mangoes are refreshing fruits. But i have doubt in : Mangoes are refreshing.

Comment: @tushain I apologize for not making myself clear; see my addition.